# "Driver [google] is not supported.", "exception": "InvalidArgumentException", while trying to add google drive as filesystem

Tags: php, google-drive-api, laravel-8

I want to use google drive as a disk of filesystem, for that I've installed `"nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive": "~1.1",` package & configured `config/filesystem.php` as below

```
'disks' => [
  'google' => [
    'driver' => 'google',
    'clientId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'clientSecret' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'refreshToken' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN'),
    'folderId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID'),
  ]
],
```

GoogleDriveServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
  Storage::extend('google', function ($app, $config) {
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($config['clientId']);
    $client->setClientSecret($config['clientSecret']);
    $client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $adapter = new \Hypweb\Flysystem\GoogleDrive\GoogleDriveAdapter($service, $config['folderId']);
    return new \League\Flysystem\Filesystem($adapter);
  });
}
```

I've set all the credentials on `.env` as below

```
FILESYSTEM_CLOUD=google
GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID=xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET=xxx
GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN=xxx
GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID=xxx
```

now if I try to get any file from google disk `Storage::disk('google')->exists('abc.jpg')` it says

> "Driver [google] is not supported.", "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like everything configured correctly but you can also check if you registered your google service provider into  `config/app.php`, if not then add it to providers array as below

```
providers=[
...
App\Providers\GoogleDriveServiceProvider::class,
],
```